# Error while loading a js as static resource in lightning Web component

Tags: community, lightning-web-components

I have a static resource name KendoUI, which is a javascript and is public. In my application, I have this :

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { loadScript, loadStyle } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import kendoUI from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/KendoUI';

export default class Lwcsheetkendoui extends LightningElement {
    kendoUIInitialized = false;

    renderedCallback() {
        if(this.kendoUIInitialized) return;
        this.kendoUIInitialized = true;
        loadScript(this, kendoUI + '/Kendo/kendo.all.min.js')
                        .then(() => { /* callback */ alert('Success'); })
                        .catch(error => {alert(error);});
    }
}
```

JS file has been not loaded and error is throwing undefined in the alert.
I tried other simple JS files and those are working fine. but I have to user KenoUI js only.

Does anyone has experienced the same issue?

Comment: can you try using promise instead as shown here?https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/create_third_party_library

Comment: @Pankaj - What is the status code when the resource is being loaded?

Comment: Do you have a specific error in the console when the script attempt to load? Can you also try to replace your `alert` with a `console.error` it should give you a better call stack.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal Same issue with Promise.

Comment: @pmdartus I tried it but it does not show any error.

Comment: Please check the file in your static resources, if the path is correct - kendoUI + '/Kendo/kendo.all.min.js'

Comment: @AnshulAgrawal - Path is correct as other CSS and JS files are loaded which is on the same path.

Comment: Getting this same behavior when attempting to load the amCharts library with loadScript.  The resources are loaded okay when the page loads (status 200).  Using Promise.all() exactly as defined in the docs.  The catch method is being fired but 'error' is undefined.  @pmdartus

Comment: While it doesn't solve the undefined error issue, I found I was able to get more information in the console by enabling debug mode in the org.  It exposed additional warning messages when the scripts were loaded.  In my case it revealed some additional dependencies in the library were missing.

Comment: @ScottMcClung The resource loader rejects only if the script fails to load (non 200 response), but not when it fails to parse or run. While it deserves updating the documentation, I also raised the question to the team to see if there is anything that we can do to better report a parsing or processing errors.

Comment: @Pankaj the network error i'm getting is 302 temporary moved, I think this is because of static resources are being served from VF domain rather than Lightining domain (recent salesforce security update)