# Is it possible to load KendoGrid in a Lightning Web Component?

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, third-party

I am trying to use Kendo Grid in Lightning.  I was running into similar issues as
this thread [Error while loading a js as static resource in lightning Web component](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/254456/error-while-loading-a-js-as-static-resource-in-lightning-web-component).

I was able to get a little further by preloading jquery then including individual java scripts instead of kendo.all.min.js. However after rendering the header the grid fails to render rows and complains about

Error: Invalid template:'<tr data-uid="#=data.uid#....
I even tried providing a column template in the column model but that did not work.

in html template I have:

```
  <div id="grid1" class="myGrid"></div>
```

in renderedCallback I have:

```
loadScript(this, KendoJS + '/jquery.min.js')
 .then(() => {

      Promise.all([
        loadStyle(this, KendoJS + '/kendo.common.min.css'),
        loadStyle(this, KendoJS + '/kendo.default.min.css'),
        loadScript(this, KendoJS + '/kendo.core.min.js'),
        loadScript(this, KendoJS + '/kendo.data.min.js'),
        loadScript(this, KendoJS + '/kendo.columnsorter.min.js'),
        loadScript(this, KendoJS + '/kendo.grid.min.js'),
      ])
      .then(() => {

        const ele = this.template.querySelector('div.myGrid');
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
        $(ele).kendoGrid({
          columns: [ {
            field: "name",
            template: "<strong>#: name # </strong>"
          }],
          dataSource: [ { name: "Jane Doe" }, { name: "John Doe2" } ]             
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
      console.error({
        message: 'Error occured on KendoGrid',
        error
      });
    })
  });
```

Has anyone successfully loaded a KendoGrid in a Ligthning Web Component?

Comment: is `<div id="grid1" class="myGrid"></div>` all your template? isn't it wrapped in <template> tags?

Comment: my full template was 
<template>
     <div id="grid1" class="myGrid"></div>
 </template>

Comment: @Drew Facing the same issue did you able to use kendo in LWC??

Comment: I did not and just used the Salesforce components. I have not revisited.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that none of the imported JavaScript files reference external URLs (e.g. CDNs) since Salesforce disallows such access as a security measure. This is probably why the all JS file fails to load. Also note that export and import statements cannot appear in the main JS static resource you load using loadScript.

Additionally, your template needs to be of the form:

```
<template>
    <div id="grid1" class="myGrid" lwc:dom="manual"></div>
</template>
```

I recommend reviewing the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/create_third_party_library) to see if there are other points you have missed.

Comment: my full template was 
<template>
     <div id="grid1" class="myGrid"></div>
 </template>

I also include the js as a local static resource and seems to be loading just fine.  Issue is within kendo somewhere.

I am following patter to similar to https://github.com/Gurenax/sfdx-lwc-fullcalendarjs

Comment: I also dont believe it is referencing external js... full error is :
Error: Invalid template:'<tr data-uid="#=data.uid#" role='row'><td class="#= data && data.dirty && data.dirtyFields && data.dirtyFields['name'] ? ' k-dirty-cell' : '' #" role='gridcell'>#= data && data.dirty && data.dirtyFields && data.dirtyFields['name'] ? '<span class="k-dirty"></span>' : '' #<strong>#: name # </strong></td></tr>'

Comment: Try adding the DOM manual attribute in the template

Comment: Adding lwc:dom="manual" did not help.  The error stack trace shows all inside kendo and seems to be related to some dynamic compilation.  
    at Object.compile (..../KendoJS/kendo.core.min.js:25:8911)
    at Object.i [as template] (.../KendoJS/jquery.min.js:2:86266)
    at init._tmpl (.../KendoJS/kendo.grid.min.js:28:18826)
    at init._templates (.../KendoJS/kendo.grid.min.js:28:21189)